# What should I consider to be an invalid password?

Tags: asp-classic, passwords

When users are choosing a password for my application, what restrictions should I apply, if any, and what should I consider to be an invalid password?

For example, I have read about trimming off whitespace, restricting only to ASCII characters, etc, but these seem to be opinions or application dependant.

I am aware of forcing *requirements* on passwords such as a minimum of two symbols, two numbers, etc. but I am more interested in what restrictions I should apply.

Comment: Why are you interested in applying restrictions to what characters are valid?

Comment: we're going to need more information. is the application highly sensitive data? will it be available via internet? app store? etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think anything should be an invalid password. If you can hash it to store it and later compare against, you should be able to use it as your password. Restricting the strength of passwords does nothing useful.

Answer (score 1):

Secure: 
Capitol Letter 
Number 
Letters

Simple: 
Letters
Numbers

Crazy: 
Everything :D

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are sanitizing input correctly I see no reason to block any characters at all.  Trailing spaces should probably be cut off though.